# Accessing a <p> tags value in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My aim is to have a button that once clicked, adds the contents of a certain 
"p" tag (in-relation to the button) inside a list. The code I have so far is;

HTML:

```
<a href="GardenFurniture.html">
  <div class="product">
    <figure class="col-sm-3" height="220" id="product" >
    <p class="PTitle"> <strong>Stylish Table and Chairs Set</strong></p>
    <img src="GardenFurnitureImages/small.jpg"/>
  </a>
    <p style="display: inline" class="price"> Price: £499 </p>
    <input style="display: inline" type='button' value='Add to Basket' class='addBasket'>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.addBasket').click(function() {
    var basketProduct = $(this).parent('.PTitle').val();
    $('<li>').text(basketProduct).appendTo('.BasketBar');
});
```

I am trying to append the contents of `Ptitle` (Stylish Table and Chairs Set) into the list `BasketBar`

This code just adds a blank space into the list any ideas on how to get my desired output?

Comment: You closed `a` tag while `figure` tag didn't closed in it.

Comment: html structure is invalid

Comment: `val()` is for input/textarea value, use `text()` for `<p>` content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your html structure is invalid, the starting and ending of tags are not proper:

`<a>` tag and `<figure>` tag are not closing properly, so have a look into it and correct html first

I am posting answer by changing some html:

```js
$('.addBasket').click(function(){
  // here we have used .siblings as we need to get text of same level element
  var basketProduct = $(this).siblings('.PTitle').text(); // use .text() for getting text inside any element
  alert(basketProduct)
  $('<li>').text(basketProduct).appendTo('.BasketBar');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <figure class="col-sm-3" height="220" id="product" >
    <p class="PTitle"> <strong>Stylish Table and Chairs Set</strong></p>
    <img src="GardenFurnitureImages/small.jpg"/>
    <p style="display: inline" class="price"> Price: £499 </p>
    <input style="display: inline" type='button' value='Add to Basket' class='addBasket'>
  </figure>
</div>
```